# Mapbox gl returning "Tile not Found"

Tags: mapbox, raster, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I'm trying to add raster tileset to my map, but it's returning "Tile not Found" although this tileset is uploaded in mapbox studio and it's valid as I can see that in studio styles.

Here is my code

```
const TiffView1 = ({ previewFile }) => {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
 useEffect(() => {
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/globhe/clh089wmj00il01qu1ojx32ic",
      // center: [57.367, 12.405],
      // zoom: 1,
    });
    map.on("load", () => {
      map.addSource("tiff-source", {
        type: "raster",
        tiles: [
          "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/globhe.8qs6d7cc/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=" +
            mapboxgl.accessToken,
        ],
        tileSize: 256,
      });

      map.addLayer({
        id: "raster-tileset-layer",
        type: "raster",
        source: "tiff-source",
        paint: {
          "raster-opacity": 0.5,
        },
      });
    });
    map.on("load", function () {
      map.resize();
    });

    // Add navigation control (the +/- zoom buttons)
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");

    // Clean up on unmount
    return () => map.remove();
  }, []);
  return <div style={styles.mapContainer} ref={mapContainerRef} />;
};
```

It gives me this error :
[image]

Where have I went wrong, or I'm missing anything ?